# Javascript variable scope and inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, variables, inheritance, scope

I'm stuck in some part of my code. I created something like model class BoardEx and I want to create Iterator for it, here's some example:

```
Game.BoardEx = function(params){
    ...
    this.board = Array(cols, rows);
    ...
}
```

where Game is the "parent" object of all children "classes". Then I declared Iterator:

```
Game.BoardEx.prototype.Iterator = function(){
    var pos = {x: 0, y: -1};
    this.next = function(){
        ...     
        return this.board[pos.x][pos.y];
    };
```

Later usage is:

```
var board = new Game.BoardEx();
var iter = new board.Iterator();
```

It seems that I can't call `this.board` in this scope. Should I use `bind` or other method or just can't I call this at all?

Comment: Aren't you missing a new

Comment: This looks like it should work, assuming you're doing `new Iterator` __and__ copying the board over (or a reference to it). Remember, `this.board` belongs to the created Iterator now and __not__ the BoardEx object. Also, you want a method like `.iterate` on the BoardEx __instance__ that does `return new Iterator(this)` with the board passed so you can have access to it.

Comment: I use it later as:
`var board = new Game.BoardEx();
var iter = new board.Iterator();`

Comment: @user3664767 Ah, I understand your problem much better now, please edit that into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access `this` of the calling object when you're inside a `new` call.

Performing a `new` "construct" call changes the context to the newly created object.

Instead, you can use a builder function:

```
Game.BoardEx.prototype.getIterator = function(){
    function Iterator(board){
        this.board = board;
        this.pos = {x:0, y:-1};
    }
    Iterator.prototype.next = function(){
       return this.board[this.pos.x][this.pos.y];
       ...
    }
    return new Iterator(this.board); // create new instance with the board.
}
```

You can define `Iterator` completely externally to the Board, as long as the getIterator function passes a valid board to it. This would also let you call it from the outside and *might* be more effecient. It will also make `instanceof` work but IMO it's really not a big deal.

Comment: I was just writing the same answer. +1 for `GetIterator` on the `BoardEx` instance. Definitely worth hiding the `Interator` constructor in closure, but maybe in the scope just above this function.

Comment: Okay, it worked like magic, but can I modify `this.board` in this scope or just iterate through it? E.g `var it = new board.getIterator(); it.setval(123);`

Comment: @user3664767 since board is an object, it is passed by reference value, you can change the contents of the board from the iterator, (but not swap the board altogether).